# how to add variable into an url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am getting userid through parsing a link.Again i have to parse it with userid to get the access.
What i am doing

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/fb_redirect_mobile/?accessToken=4546"];
```

This gives me the userid,now i want to use that userid to parse it again such as:

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/userid/bookmarks"];
```

In other languages I have seen they are just using:

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/"+userid+"/bookmarks"];
```

The userid variable takes user id.how i can do this in iPhone.I know my question is lengthy but i tried to make it clear what i want.please help..please also tell me how to store a parsing id into string,such as userid i am going to get after parsing the url./now how i can save it in form of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give like this,

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/%@/bookmarks",userid];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *userId = @"123456";
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/%@/bookmarks", userId];
```

`initWithFormat:`/`stringWithFormat:` follow the [general format convention set by printf/scanf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)

Comment: In my camera app when i clicks the image its going to be saved but i want before getting saved it will ask user for title and description for image.How i can do this?? Please help..

Answer (score 2):

The way you concatenated your userid is not valid syntax in Obj-C

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/"+userid+"/bookmarks"];
```

What you'd probably want to do is use a format specifier for an Obj-C object (in your case `NSString`), and use that within your URL (assuming `userid` is an NSString, which it probably is. If it's a C based string, use `%s` as your format specifier instead).

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/%@/bookmarks", userid];
```

Refer to these on how to use `stringWithFormat:` on an `NSString`:

- [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)
- [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)

Comment: In my camera app when i clicks the image its going to be saved but i want before getting saved it will ask user for title and description for image.How i can do this?? Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/"+userid+"/bookmarks"];
```

You would use

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/user/%@/bookmarks",userid];
```

Comment: In my camera app when i clicks the image its going to be saved but i want before getting saved it will ask user for title and description for image.How i can do this?? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Well you almost got it:

```
NSString *usrid = @"4546";
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/fb_redirect_mobile/?accessToken=%@", userid];
```

You can use the [`stringWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_) method of [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot...can you tell me i am getting userid from the json parsing...then how to store it into a variable..

Comment: Not really since I don't know how the JSON looks like or you code. I suggest you pick up a book about Objective-C development, these question are really simple.

Comment: @deepak This will be another question, as it's on an entirely different topic

Comment: I am new to iPhone.so,i dont know many thing about it..thanks for supporting me..

Comment: @rckoenes In my camera app when i clicks the image its going to be saved but i want before getting saved it will ask user for title and description for image.How i can do this?? Please help..

Comment: @deepak thats an new question that you should ask in a new post, also you should try to solve it your self. If you know how to save an image you can easily add an extra view that ask the user for a title and description.

Comment: i have asked in new post..bt nt getting any reply..this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632741/how-to-add-a-xib-with-camera#comment18699839_13632741